# Easiest way to have an RSS feed with group contributions?

Tags: rss, blog

Our development team regularly sends each other links to read. Email isn't the best format for this; we'd like for all of us to be able to contribute to an RSS feed that we can all consume via Google Reader or whatever.

I thought about using Blogger for this. Any better ideas? If it can be private, that's nice, but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very easy to set up a WordPress blog with multiple contributors, either on your own server or free at wordpress.com.  Mind you, Blogger would also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If all you team members maintain their own blogs you could use an feed aggregator like [planet](http://www.planetplanet.org/) running on your own hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Delicious is great for this and I've used it in this way. Team members can contribute links using the web interface, browser add-on or bookmarklet and you can all subscribe to the [subsequent feeds](http://www.delicious.com/help/feeds).

You can set individual link posts to private and the tags are a good way to organise contributions from different team members in a single account. Alternatively, you can  create an organisational account as well as one for each team member and aggregate these http://civicactions.com/blog/aggregating_delicious_bookmarks_from_multiple_people.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out RTC ( http://jazz.net ) it does this natively for your development team. So you can subscribe to about any rss feed including the build rss feed , the team, someone specific etc... etc... Check out the google widget example.